# Django: Relationship between 3 models

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I'm working on an app for construction company, and I want to create our daily schedule. For this matter, I have 3 models Date, Construction_site and Machinery. Each day we are working on several construction sites and we have 3-4 machines/vehicles per CS.

I want to get something like this, but I'm stuck with the relationships between models.

```
2023-09-21
Construction site 1
Excavator 1
Excavator 2
Truck 1
Construction site 2
Excavator 3
Excavator 4
Truck 2
Construction site 3
Buldozer
Truck 3

2023-09-22
Construction site 1
Excavator 1
Excavator 2
Truck 1
Construction site 2
Excavator 3
Truck 2
Construction site 3
Buldozer
Excavator 4
Truck 3
```

Simplified models:

```
class Date(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()

class Construction_site(models.Model):
    construction_site_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.ManyToManyField(Date)

class Machinery(models.Model):
    machine_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    construction_site_name = models.ManyToManyField(Construction_site)
```

Once my models are correct I need to create a view that will show all construction sites and used machinery for the specific date.

```
def date(request):
    date = Date.objects.get(id=1)
    construction_sites = date.construction_site_set.all()
```

This will return all construction sites for the specific date, but I'm unable to get used machinery.

I'm fairly new to Django, so any help is welcome.

Comment: Your models are a bit confusing. Why do you have a model just for date?

Comment: You're right. I already have a "working product" without Date model, but it's a little bit annoying to choose date for each machine for each construction site every time. 
So I thought of simplifying it with creating Date model and then choosing construction sites and machinery for the specific date.

Comment: Hi Teofilex, could you give me some more context information. like are these 3 models contain unique records. I mean if the `Construction_site` have an object lets say 'Site 1' then that will not be repeated ? and one more thing you need to fetch the date details by specifying the the id ?

Answer (score 0):

You filter by following relations:

```
def date(request):
    matchinery = Machinery.objects.filter(construction_site_name__date__pk=1)
    # …
```

but you can also enumerate the machinery for each site with:

```
{% for site in sites %}
    {{ site.construction_site_name }}
    {% for machinery in site.machinery_set.all %}
        {{ machinery.machine_name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

with:

```
def date(request):
    sites = Construction_site.objects.filter(date__pk=1)
    # …
```

and pass this as `sites` to the context of the template.

---

> **Note**: A `ForeignKey` does *not* store the string representation (or name) of the
> referenced object in the column, it stores the primary key of the record it
> references in a column with an  `_id` suffix to a `ForeignKey` field. Therefore
> `ForeignKey`s usually do *not* end with a `_name` suffix. You might want to
> consider renaming the <s>`construction_site_name`</s> field to `construction_sites`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The results I'm getting in the template are OK with your method, but relationships between models I've created are still wrong. I've tried to add ManyToMany relationship between Date and Machine, but I'm still not able to do it right. [test.png](https://postimg.cc/JsqzfBym)

I'll probably stick with my first solution.

class DailySchedule(models.Model):
  date = models.DateField()
  machine = models.ForeignKey(Machine, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  construction_sites = models.ForeignKey(ConstructionSite, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: Can can select multiple ones by using `Ctrl` and selecting multiple ones, that is how HTML implemented a `<select multiple>`.

Comment: You can add the m2m fields in `filter_vertical` of the `ModelAdmin` to make manipulating the m2m more convenient. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_vertical

Comment: I'll try it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the model definition will be better if

```
class Schedule(models.Model): #the date model before
    date = models.DateField(unique=True)

class Construction_site(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)

class Machinery(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Plan(models.Model):
   schedule = models.ForeignKey(Schedule,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   site = models.ForeignKey(Construction_site,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   machinery = models.ForeignKey(Machinery,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

now your query will be come something like bellow

```
def schedule_for_the_day(request):
    required_date = datetime.datetime.today()
    plan = Plan.objects.filter(schedule__date=required_date).all()
```

now you can use the `plan` list and `regroup` from `template filters` together to achive the required output.

you can also use `schedule__id` for  fetching and improve the query perfomance by using `select_related'

```
Plan.objects.filter(schedule__id=1).select_related('schedule').select_related('site').select_related('machinery')
```